# Applying max min and last index within a pandas groupby function Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, datetime

The code down below separates the data in months with the `month_changes`. The `Values` and `Val_dates` are correlated, `Val_dates` are supposed to be the matching dates for the Values indexes.

So `[100,'2015-11-01 01:03:00'],[123, '2015-11-08 12:56:00']......` Each row in the multidimensional array is suppose to represent a single month so the first row `[100,123,135.3,139.05,156.08,163.88,173.72]` is for the November of 2015 and the sixth row `[163,173.12]` is for February of 2016 etc.

It outputs the last index of each month so the output for the first row would be `123`. The output of the function till it reaches the `agg.` is `array([list([100.0, 123.0, 135.3, 139.05, 156.08]), list([0]), list([0]), list([163.88, 173.72]), 0], dtype=object)`.

How can I add a code to the already existing code so that it outputs the `max min` and `last index` of each array. Resulting the Expected output below.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

Values = np.array(
    [
        [100, 123, 135.3, 139.05, 156.08, 163.88, 173.72],
        [100, 123, 135.3, 139.05, 156.08, 163.88, 173.72],
        [100, 123, 135.3, 139.05, 156.08, 163.88, 173.72],
        [100, 123, 135.3, 139.05, 156.08, 163.88, 173.72],
        [100, 123, 135.3, 139.05, 156.08, 163.88, 173.72],
        [100, 123, 135.3, 139.05, 156.08, 163.88, 173.72],
        [100, 123, 135.3, 139.05, 156.08, 163.88, 173.72],
    ]
)

Values = np.array([arr[i:] for i, arr in enumerate(Values.tolist())])

Val_dates = [
    "2015-11-01 01:03:00",
    "2015-11-08 12:56:00",
    "2015-11-11 02:30:00",
    "2015-11-14 04:23:00",
    "2015-11-14 05:23:00",
    "2016-02-11 02:00:00",
    "2016-02-15 15:00:00",
]

df = pd.DataFrame({"dt": Val_dates, "val": Values}).astype({"dt": "datetime64"})
idx = pd.date_range("2015-11-01 00:00:00", "2016-03-01 00:00:00", freq="MS")

display(
    df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="MS", key="dt"))["val"]
    .apply(lambda x: x.head(1).squeeze()[: len(x)] if len(x) else [0])
    .reindex(idx, fill_value=0)
    .to_numpy()
    .agg(
        # Get max of the duration column for each group
        max_duration=(lambda x: np.max(x)),
        # Get min of the duration column for each group
        min_duration=(lambda x: np.min(x)),
        # Last indexes
        last_index=(lambda x: x[len(x) - 1]),
    )
)
```

Expected Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, given what the last functional part of your code outputs:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
...
arr = (
    df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="MS", key="dt"))["val"]
    .apply(lambda x: x.head(1).squeeze()[: len(x)] if len(x) else [0])
    .reindex(idx, fill_value=0)
    .to_numpy()
)
print(arr)
# Outputs a list of lists and one integer
[[100.0, 123.0, 135.3, 139.05, 156.08], [0], [0], [163.88, 173.72], 0]
```

You could try this:

```py
new_df = pd.DataFrame({"dates": idx})

for i, item in enumerate(list(arr)):
    if not isinstance(item, list):
        item = [item]
    new_df.loc[i, "min"] = min(item)
    new_df.loc[i, "max"] = max(item)
    new_df.loc[i, "lastindex"] = item[len(item) - 1]
```

Then:

```py
print(new_df)
# Outputs
       dates     min     max  lastindex
0 2015-11-01  100.00  156.08     156.08
1 2015-12-01    0.00    0.00       0.00
2 2016-01-01    0.00    0.00       0.00
3 2016-02-01  163.88  173.72     173.72
4 2016-03-01    0.00    0.00       0.00
```